# Why does my shell say: From: too many arguments

Tags: python, ubuntu, bioinformatics, biopython

### Goal

I'm a new student of bioinformatics and I wanted to use a program which changes a FASTQ file into a GBK file.

### Background

I'm using Windows OS on which I'm using a VirtualBox to run an Ubuntu environment. I've heard that Linux-like systems are better for bioinformatics (again, I'm very new to this).
I go to this site: http://sequenceconversion.bugaco.com/converter/biology/sequences/fastq_to_genbank.php

### Steps to Error

I follow the instructions for installing `biopython` given via this site. On the commandline in Ubuntu I write:

```bash
pip install biopython
pip install --upgrade biopython
```

Then I continue to follow the instructions given by the site and write the first line of code in the command line:

```bash
from Bio import SeqIO
```

which yields the following error:

> from: too many arguments

### Question

I don't understand why this is going wrong. Does the commandline work differently?

Sorry for this beginner question and I hope I formulated my question properly.

Comment: The commands are in a script (file), that should be run from python like  `python3 file` (or python, or biopython). What you did was interpreted by the terminal shell (bash)

Comment: Okay thank you. I've tried continueing with Spyder and i got a lot further there.

Comment: From Bio import SeqIO not sure would works try from Bio import SeqIO too

Comment: run `which from` to check the command you are running instead of the intended python `import`

Answer (score -1):

You may try to write like this

`import SeqIO from Bio`